# Terraform - Retrieve Azure AD Group Member Name

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform

In my Terraform configuration, I want to obtain the names of all members of an Azure AD Group called "`VaultUsers`" and then read and display the result from my Terraform output file called `outputs.tf`.

I have two snippets of Terraform configuration that complete part of the above task, as described below.

**[ Snippet 1 ]**

This first code block will display the object ids of the group members. Unfortunately, the `test.group.` object does not include a property to display the group member names and so for now, I'm simply displaying the Azure AD object id of each group member by using the notation - `data.azuread_group.test_group.members`.

```
data "azuread_group" "test_group" {
  display_name = "VaultUsers"
}

output "azuread_groups_root-users" {
  value = data.azuread_group.test_group.members
}
```

The second snippet (below) on the other hand, will display a large chunk of Azure AD metadata for each group member, including the following:

```
 + mail_nicknames
 + object_ids
 + user_principal_names
```

**[ Snippet 2 ]**

```
data "azuread_users" "users" {
 return_all = true
}

output "azuread_groups_root-user-members" {
  value = data.azuread_users.users
}
```

Crucially, it also displays the below additional metadata in a `users` block and ultimately, it is the `display_name` value that I'm desperately seeking to extract. Any idea or suggestions on how I can achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Yup, `data.azuread_users.users["display_name"]` or maybe even `data.azuread_users.users.display_name`. :)

Comment: Uh, sorry, it's a list, so: `data.azuread_users.users[0]["display_name"]` or `data.azuread_users.users[0].display_name`.

Comment: Thank you @MarkoE. I'm afraid though that neither of those suggestions work.

Comment: Can you add the error to the question then?

Comment: Apologies @MarkoE. Your last suggestion worked to a degree, as I'm now able to display the group member whose name is set at array index [0]. As I'm looking to list an entire group of users, I've replaced the zero index with the wildcard character and this has managed to display all azure ad users. Now, I mentioned that it worked to a degree, simply because what I need now is to display members of a named Azure AD group, not all Azure AD users per se.

Comment: Wait, you need to display things from both snippets or not? Has the question changed the scope now?

Comment: The first snippet references a Terraform data block (azuread_group) from which I'd like to extract the required metadata, i.e. the member name. Unfortunately, Terraform doesn't appear to provide an attribute for that data block which could be exported to display group member names. The second snippet on the other hand references a Terraform data block (azuread_users) which provides an exportable attribute for member names, which is what I'm looking for, hence my reference to it to provide some further clarity. In other words, the first snippet is where I'd like to extract the member name.

Comment: Ah, ok, so instead of IDs you want to see something human readable? Is there such a data source which could provide a mapping between an object ID and a name? I'm thinking some kind of a combination of output of one data source could be used as an input for another one which would do the mapping.

Comment: Precisely!! Rather than having the group member details displayed as Object IDs, I'd like them displayed by Name............which is what the azuread_users provides but sadly isn't the data block I'm seeking to query.

Comment: If you use the output of the first data source and then use `object_ids` value to query the second data source, would that work?

Comment: That could work, but will require some fairly complex logic. More importantly, it would also mean having to always iterate through an entire Azure AD user list to perform a find and match, which would be a bit of an overkill. I like to keep my code fairly simple if possible.

Comment: Well, I guess Azure have a feature request on their hands. :D

Comment: I reckon I could probably lean towards the Azure CLI command az ad group member list --group to obtain the desired outcome. Some bit of manipulation should enable me access the displayName attribute for that command output. Just need to figure out how to incorporate Azure CLI into my Terraform configuration.

Comment: This could help: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource.

Comment: Thanks. Ironically, I also just stumbled upon an article that mentioned the use of a Provisioner block and I was just in the process of testing it out.